# The meaning of the ampersand

Tags: ampersand

In this line:

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&msg=' + msg;
```

What does the ampersand(`&`) mean?

Comment: I think it is querystring separator in this context

Answer (score 2):

I think the ampersands are meant for **query string separation** from each other

```
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&msg=' + msg;
```

becomes

```
var dataString = 'name=John Doe&email=johndoe@gmail.com&subject=some email subject&msg=hey activate your account';
```

This can then be appended to your Url

```
var finalUrl = "http://mysite.com?" + dataString;
```